# Problem with path when trying to write a file with a defined name given before by the code in Python

Tags: python, path, page-title

I'm having issues when I try to write a file in Python giving it a certain name and not only pathing it. Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
page_title=page.find('title')

raw_data_path ='output/'+page_title+'_raw.txt'
print (page_title)

with open(raw_data_path, 'w') as file:
   file.write ()
```

When running this code, I receive the error `[Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'output/myfile_raw.txt'`

If instead of `raw_data_path ='output/'+page_title+'_raw.txt'` I put, for example, `raw_data_path ='output/'+'_raw.txt'` the code works well, so for some reason I can't combine the path with the name I'm trying to give the file.

I've searched that error and I see that it is a routing error, so it might be happening because when I want to add the page_title something happens with the path, but I can't see which is the mistake because it should be working.

Can someone give me some help with this issue?